# Increment the value of count in one function and use if condition on count in another function

Tags: java, android, function

I declare a count variable, I want to increase the value of count when the function  is called and count become again zero when user send to Main activity but the problem is when the function is called value is increased but it does not increase in another function. Value of count increases when the function is called but value of count remain same when I call it in another function that is zero

```
package com.codewithosama.socialapp;        
        
public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final static int gallery_pick = 1;

    // Here I declare count
    int count = 0;
    
    // Remaining code
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
        filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        
                        // Here I am increasing value of count
                        usersRef.child("profile image").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(selfIntent);
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Image Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            count = count + 1;
                                            Log.d("count", String.valueOf(count));
                                        } else {
                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error:" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                });

            }

        });
    }

    // Remaining Code
    private void saveAccountSetupInfo() {
        Log.d("count", String.valueOf(count));
        String user_name = userName.getText().toString();
        String full_name = fullName.getText().toString();
        String country = countryName.getText().toString();
        // Log.d("uri",ImageUri.toString());

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user_name)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter UserName ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (count == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a profile Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(full_name)) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Full Name ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(country)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Country ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            usersRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        sendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Your account updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error occured :" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    // Here I am again assinging value of count zero
    private void sendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will a lot easier to answer if you try to reduce this to a minimal compilable example and format it with proper indentation. As it is now, it is a bit hard to follow all these levels of nesting.

Comment: please align your code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare count globally public and static like: `public static int count = 0`. By Doing this you can use the variable count in another function as well as in another class by typing: `SetupActivity.count`.